# MySQL Full Text Search way too slow

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am doing a search on a table which has around 2M entries. When I'm doing the basic search, the request time is below 0.1 sec:

```
SELECT * FROM entreprises WHERE MATCH (L1, LIBVOIE, LIBCOM) 
                                AGAINST(:term2 IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 0,10
```

Which is correct, but when I put the relevance part of the query:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(L1,LIBVOIE, LIBCOM) AGAINST(:term) as score 
FROM entreprises 
WHERE MATCH (L1, LIBVOIE, LIBCOM) AGAINST(:term2 IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

query time jumps to tens of seconds.

Can someone explain why is that happening?

Comment: What does `explain select ...` say?

Comment: is there a index on  "score" ?

Comment: You're doing two essentially unrelated things here with the full text index.  The score isn't `IN BOOLEAN MODE` (which makes sense since iirc that doesn't have a ranking) but it also may not be an especially meaningful value. I concur that `EXPLAIN SELECT` may be valuable, but the way fulltext interacts with the optimizer, it may not reveal much.

Comment: You *might* actually get what you want with this admittedly counterintuitive variation: `SELECT *, MATCH(L1,LIBVOIE, LIBCOM) AGAINST(:term) as score FROM entreprises WHERE MATCH(L1,LIBVOIE, LIBCOM) AGAINST(:term) AND MATCH (L1, LIBVOIE, LIBCOM) AGAINST(:term2 IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 0,10;`